# Displaying a journal entry and joining with main table

Tags: postgresql

I have a journal system that has a table structure like:

```
[journal_logs]
id
title
created_at

[journal_entries]
id
journal_log_id
body
created_at
```

So a "journal_log" is made up of one or more "entries".

On my webpage I want to list the most recent logs, along with the entries.

Example:

```
"Log 10"
  "entry 1"
  "entry 2"
  "entry 3"

"Log 9"
 "entry 1"

"Log 8"
 "entry 1"
 "entry 2"
```

Is it possible to produce an output like this with a single query?

Answer (score 0):

here is example with `<UL><LI>`

**data sample:**

```
t=# create table journal_logs(id int,title text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# create table journal_entries(id int,journal_log_id int);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into journal_logs select 8,'a';
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into journal_logs select 9,'a';
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into journal_logs select 10,'a';
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into journal_entries select 1,8;
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into journal_entries select 2,8;
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into journal_entries select 1,9;
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into journal_entries select 1,10;
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into journal_entries select 2,10;
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into journal_entries select 3,10;
INSERT 0 1
```

**query sample:**

```
t=# with p as (
 select concat('<ul>',l.id,l.title) ul,concat('<li>',e.id) li
 from journal_logs l
 join journal_entries e on l.id = journal_log_id
)
select
 concat(
  case when li = min(li) over (partition by ul order by li) then ul end
 ,concat(li, case when li = max(li) over (partition by ul) then '</ul>' end)) html
from p;
       html
------------------
 <ul>10a<li>1
 <li>2
 <li>3</ul>
 <ul>8a<li>1
 <li>2</ul>
 <ul>9a<li>1</ul>
(6 rows)
```

```html
<ul>10a<li>1
 <li>2
 <li>3</ul>
 <ul>8a<li>1
 <li>2</ul>
 <ul>9a<li>1</ul>
```